# A simpler derivation of ($\phi \lor (\neg \phi)$)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

In *Chiswell&Hodges* [Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199215626) (2007)] they use this derivation to prove ($\phi \lor (\neg \phi)$):

[image]

A page earlier they used a **simpler** derivation that could also have been used to prove ($\phi \lor (\neg \phi)$). Can you check that I am not mistaken?

[image]

At the last step they add $\neg$ to $(\neg(\phi \lor (\neg \phi)))$ and get $(\neg(\neg(\phi \lor (\neg \phi))))$. But they could have used *Reduction Ad Absurdum rule* and removed the negation and gotten $(\phi \lor (\neg \phi))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

Your second example is [page 28] :

> **Example 2.7.1** :We prove the sequent  $(¬(¬(φ ∨ (¬φ))))$.

See the final comment :

> [...] At first sight it looks as if the two ¬ signs at the beginning of the conclusion have made extra work for us. This is not so. The sequent $(φ ∨ (¬φ))$ is certainly valid, but it is just as hard to prove; in fact the proof needs (RAA).

Comment: The authors say that 'it is just as hard to prove,' and then give a more harder prove. That was what confused me.

Comment: @Graduate - You are right; I think that the authors are interested to show us different "proof strategies". The proof of $(φ ∨ (¬φ))$ can be shortened a little bit repeating the previous one with a final (RAA). What is of interest - I think - is the fact that we need (RAA).